# Why is UItableViewCell viewWithTag returning nil?

Tags: uitableview, viewwithtag

I am using IOX8 and Xcode 6. I created a table with a customtype cell in storyboard, and I placed a label in it. I entered a tag number for the label in the IB, so that I could retrieve a reference to the label in my code. 
But when I try to get  a reference to the label inside my "cellForRowAtIndexPath", using viewWithTag I get a NIL for the label :

This are the two lines of code that are important in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];


UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

The "cell viewWithTag:1" line returns NIL, I don't understand why.

I also tried "cell.contentView withWithTag:1" and that did not work either.

Is this a bug in IOS 8 or Xcode 6?

thanks

-Malena

Comment: What about cell? Is it returning nil for cell as well? In my case I am getting nil for cell.

Comment: Answer to this Question is [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344106/viewwithtag-returns-nil-on-uitableviewcell-only-first-time

Comment: Maybe you are loading data before view is visible... try to reloadData in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 11):

Uncheck Size Classes option in the storyboard and clean & build the app.
It should work now.

Comment: Is there a workaround if I need **Size Classes** to be enabled?

Comment: Uncheck clean & build and recheck Size classes option

Answer (score 5):

I met the same problem when I was using IOS8 and Xcode 6.1. I found that if I enable the `Size Classes`, `viewWithTag` always return `nil`. I think it may be a bug for Xcode 6.x. Just disable the `Size Classes`, everything goes ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make the view '`installed`', check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html):

Comment: Some serious work needs to be done on this "installed" size classes!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug View Hierarchy.

- Run your application in debug mode;
- Goto view, where UITableViewController sits;
- In Xcode click: Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy;
- Inspect weather tag(s) are assigned properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the initial view controller was my tableview, then everything worked as expected.   When it came from another view controller I had issues.

In my case, in previous view controller I had:

```
RoutePreview *rs = [[RoutePreview alloc] init];
rs.rota = [availableRoutes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:rs animated:YES];
```

I've replaced this with

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SBIPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
RoutePreview *xpto = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RouteSummary"];
xpto.rota = [availableRoutes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:xpto animated:YES];
```

The issue was gone.

Basically instead of instantiate the tableviewcontroller directly, instantiate it by the identifier, and no more nill cell in `tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` or `cell viewWithTag:` returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakingly made 2 prototypes of `UITableViewCell`, one on the storyboard where I gave it the tag number and one in my code where I registered the Nib file of it. This caused a mix up and I couldn't get a hold of the view with the tag.
My e.g.,

`let nib = UINib(nibName: "DetailTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "headerViewCell")`

Removing the above snippet from my code solved the problem. Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.