# ViewWithTag: returns nil on UITableViewCell only first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When UITableViewCell is loaded first time from Storyboard via  *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:* *viewWithTag:* returns nil object. But on second and next reloads it returns proper object.

My *tableView* is embedded in UIViewController(in Storyboard) with prototype cells

```
cellAttachment = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellAttachment"];
UIButton *btnAttachment = nil;
btnAttachment = (UIButton*)[cellAttachment viewWithTag:10];
```

When *cellAttachment* is loaded first time, *btnAttachment* is nil.
On next reload *btnAttachment* is returned properly.

**Cell View hierarchy first load**

```
(lldb) po [cellAttachment recursiveDescription]
<UITableViewCell: 0x7fd3e611cc20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e611be00>>
   | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fd3e3fc9850; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd3e611b6a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e611bd00>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7fd3e611cf20; frame = (0 -1; 15 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e611c020>>
```

**Cell view hierarchy on next reloads**

```
    (lldb) po [cellAttachment recursiveDescription]
    <UITableViewCell: 0x7fd3e611cc20; frame = (0 179; 320 42); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e611be00>>
       | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fd3e3fc9850; frame = (0 0; 320 42); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd3e611b6a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e611bd00>>
       |    | <UIButton: 0x7fd3e611d0f0; frame = (286 6; 15 22); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 10; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e611c0b0>>
       |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fd3e6015410; frame = (0.5 1; 14 20); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e3ccd960>>
       | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7fd3e611cf20; frame = (0 -1; 15 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e611c020>>

   | <UIView: 0x7fd3e3c4c140; frame = (15 41; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd3e3cecb40>>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After having the issue I compared my old working files with new storyboard files to know what may cause such a behavior. After doing that I was able to fix my problem in one of following ways.

**1: Enable 'Installed' field on each subview of UITableViewCell**

[image]

**OR**

**2: Disable 'Use size classes' on .storyboard file**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me as well. No idea why this is required though

Comment: Still a problem on iPhone 5 models on iOS11+ but not for iPhone 6. Seems to be because on iPhone 5 some cellForRow are only called once whereas on iPhone 6 they're called twice and the second time thru the view is not nil.Using option 1 solved it. Thank you.